# Implementing withSession(ClientSession session) method of Spring Data MongoDB MongoDbFactory interface

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on an implementation of the interface MongoDbFactory, however I am stuck at implementing the withSession(ClientSession session) method. Spring Data MongoDB version in use is 2.2.8.RELEASE.

```
    /**
     * Obtain a {@link ClientSession} bound instance of {@link MongoDbFactory} returning {@link MongoDatabase} instances
     * that are aware and bound to the given session.
     *
     * @param session must not be {@literal null}.
     * @return never {@literal null}.
     * @since 2.1
     */
    MongoDbFactory withSession(ClientSession session);
```

I have tried looking at the implementations found in the original library but still I'm not sure how should  I proceed. Any help is appreciated, especially on the meaning of the part that it says 'aware and bound to the given session.'

Answer (score 0):

Take a look `SimpleMongoDbFactory` implementation and/or `MongoDatabaseUtils.doGetMongoDatabase(...)` method